# What is the difference between chunk and non-chunk streaming in Erlang/Yaws

Tags: erlang, yaws

What is the difference between  `yaws_api:stream_process_deliver(Socket, IoList)` and 
 `yaws_api:stream_process_deliver_chunk(Socket, IoList)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `yaws_api:stream_process_deliver(Socket, IoList)` and `yaws_api:stream_process_deliver_chunk(Socket, IoList)` has to do with [HTTP 1.1 Transfer Coding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6). The first function transfers the provided data as is to the HTTP client, while the second uses chunked transfer to send the data to the client.

Please see section 7.5 of the [Yaws PDF documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/yaws.pdf) for more details.